# Problema en re-direccionamiento React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-hooks

Estoy haciendo un para luego identificar si un usuario esta logueado, pero estoy teniendo problema que luego de que el usuario se logue no se redireccione correctamente. Se setean los valores en el localStorage pero la pagina refesca y sigue en "auth/login". Pero si luego refresco manualmente re direcciona a "/".
Es como que redirecciona mas rapido de lo que se ejecuta el control de logueo.

AuthProvedier

```
import { createContext, useState, useEffect } from "react"
import clientAxios from "../config/axios";

export const AuthContext = createContext();

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [token, setToken] = useState(localStorage.getItem("token") || null);
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null);

    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
        authUser();
    }, [])

    const authUser = async () => {
        
        if (token) {
            try {
                const { data } = await clientAxios.get('/api/user', {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                    },
                })

                setAuth(data);
            } catch (error) {
                localStorage.removeItem("user");
                setAuth(null)
            } finally {
                setIsLoading(false); // Finaliza la carga, ya sea éxito o error
            }
        }

        if(!token){
            localStorage.removeItem("user");
            setIsLoading(false);
        }
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                auth,
                isLoading
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default AuthContext;
```

useAuth

```
import { useContext } from "react"
import {AuthContext} from "../context/AuthProvider"

const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(AuthContext);
}

export default useAuth;
```

Login

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

import clientAxios from "../../config/axios";
import { toast } from 'react-toastify'
import useAuth from "../../hooks/useAuth";

export const Login = () => {

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const emailRef = useRef();
  const passwordRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = async e => {

    e.preventDefault()

    const user = {
      'email': emailRef.current.value,
      'password': passwordRef.current.value
    }

    try {
      const { data } = await clientAxios.post('/api/login', user)
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.token)
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(data.user))

      navigate("/");

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center w-screen h-full my-5">
        <div className="text-center font-black uppercase text-4xl">
          <h1 className="block">Inicio de sesion</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="flex justify-center">
          <div className="md:flex md:justify-center md:gap-10 md:p-5 md:items-center">
            <div className="md:w-6/12">
              <img
                src="../img/register.jpeg"
                alt="Imagen de registro"
                className="rounded-lg shadow-border"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="sm:mt-6 md:w-4/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg shadow-xl">
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <div className="mb-2">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="email"
                    className="mb-1 uppercase block font-bold text-gray-600"
                  >
                    email
                  </label>
                  <input
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    ref={emailRef}
                    type="email"
                    placeholder="Tu email"
                    className="p-2 border w-full rounded-lg focus:border-red-800 focus:outline-none"
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3">
                  <label
                    htmlFor="password"
                    className="mb-1 uppercase block font-bold text-gray-600"
                  >
                    password
                  </label>
                  <input
                    id="password"
                    name="password"
                    ref={passwordRef}
                    type="password"
                    placeholder="Tu password"
                    className="p-2 border w-full rounded-lg focus:border-red-800 focus:outline-none "
                  />
                </div>
                <div className="mb-3 flex gap-1">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="remember" />
                  <label htmlFor="remember" className="text-gray-500 text-sm">
                    Recordarme
                  </label>
                </div>
                <input
                  type="submit"
                  value="Ingresar"
                  className="w-full bg-red-600 hover:bg-red-800 cursor-pointer text-white uppercase font-bold p-2 rounded-lg"
                />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

Y asi verifico en el layout si esta identificado o no

```
import { Outlet, Navigate } from "react-router-dom"
import { NavBar } from "../helpers/NavBar"
import useAuth from "../hooks/useAuth"
import { Loading } from "../helpers/Loading";

export const Layout = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();

  if (!auth) {
    return <Navigate to='/auth/login' />
  }

  return (
    <>
      <NavBar />
      <div className="mx-10">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba pasando la funcion ***setAuth*** a las props compartidas de ***AuthProvider***:

```
return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
      value={{
        auth,
        isLoading,
        setAuth
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
```

Usas esa función dentro de *'handleSubmit'* de Login.jsx:

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const user = {
      email: emailRef.current.value,
      password: passwordRef.current.value,
    };

    try {
      const {data: { data }} = // esta forma de destructuring ignorala, tu sabras como llegan tus datos desde la API
        await clientAxios.post("http://localhost:3002/api/login", user);
      localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);
      localStorage.setItem("user", data.user);
      setAuth(data.user); // seteando auth
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

y finalmente en Layout.jsx:

```
export const Layout = () => {
  const { auth } = useAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!auth) {
      navigate('/auth/login') // asegurate de importar navigate
    }
  }, [auth]) // useEffect se ejecutara en cada cambio de 'auth', si este auth esta vacio, redirige a la pagina de login, sino devuelve esta pagina

  return (
    <>
      <div className="mx-10">
        <Outlet />
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Asi te aseguras de que 'auth' tenga algún valor al momento de redireccionar a '/' y entonces el useEffect del componente Layout no redireccionara a Login. Pruébalo y me cuentas si te funciona.